# Rack-Attack: Array of IP addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rackattack

I'm trying to create an array of IP addresses so that when the application is ran Rack-Attack can identify from the set of IP addresses that are allowed to access the application. So what I have done is as followed:

```
  a = "127.0.0.1"
  Rack::Attack.blacklist('allow from localhost') do |req|
    p "#{'127.0.0.1' == req.ip} "
   a != req.ip 
  end
```

The above works, so localhost can access the application but I have tried the following below which seems to not work what so ever:

```
a = "127.0.0.1", "1.2.3.4"
  Rack::Attack.blacklist('allow from localhost') do |req|
    a.select{|x| x != req.ip}.join("")
  end
```

Can someone explain what the correct way would be to do this. You can see that I create an array. I want `Rack::Attack` to detect whether the IP address in the array has access or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way to do this would be to use a [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), a container that's like an array but provides fast lookup on individual, unique elements.

So, rewritten with that in mind:

```
allowed = %w[ 127.0.0.1 1.2.3.4 ].to_set

Rack::Attack.blacklist('allow from localhost') do |req|
  !allowed.include?(req.ip)
end
```

In your original declaration:

```
a = "x", "y"
```

In this case `a` is assigned to the first thing in that list, `"x"`, and the rest is ignored.

Comment: You mentioning `to_set` triggered one of the key points the guy mentioned in the rails conf 2014 video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=m1UwxsZD6sw#t=1437 but he does `BANNED_IPS = Set.new['1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8']` But thank you

Comment: `Set.new([...])` and `[...].to_set` are two ways to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

First off it would be nice if you were more explicit about creating an array and write

```
a = ["127.0.0.1", "1.2.3.4"]
```

but it's even better to use `Set`

```
allowed = Set.new['127.0.0.1', '1.2.3.4']
```

(also using single-quotes should save time as Ruby treats such string as literal, opposed to double-quotes)

To check if element is a member of an array you should use [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) so the code becomes

```
Rack::Attack.blacklist('allow from localhost') do |req|
  !a.include? req.ip
end
```

Comment: Prior to your answer I tried this momentarily ago. I was following https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#blacklists. However this only specifies one particular IP address. I want to specify an array of IP address's. Thank you for acknowledging the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but I didn't like the `Array#include?` solution so I went ahead and added 2 new methods for `safelist` and `blocklist` each to have support for the same. Sharing it here as it will help other users too. It can be found in [forked rack_attack branch](https://github.com/md-farhan-memon/rack-attack/tree/support_for_array_of_ip_addresses).

**Usage:**

**Safelisting:**

```rb
# config/initializers/rack_attack.rb (for rails app)

ALLOWED_IPS = %w[127.0.0.1 ::1 5.6.7.8 123.456.789.0/24]

Rack::Attack.safelist_ips(ALLOWED_IPS)
```

**Blocklisting:**

```rb
# config/initializers/rack_attack.rb (for rails apps)

BLOCKED_IPS = %w[1.2.3.4 123.456.789.0/24]

Rack::Attack.blocklist_ips(BLOCKED_IPS)
```