# How do I rate limit page requests by IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting hit numerous times by crawlers on a page which triggers an API call. I would like to limit access to that page for bots who do not respect my robots.txt.

*Note: This question is not a duplicate.. I want rate limiting not IP blacklisting.*

Comment: Maybe use `rack-attack` gem to whitelist bots that you want to allow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rack-Attack: Array of IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915107/rack-attack-array-of-ip-addresses)

Comment: I think that @kimgrey's response is more relevant seeing that I want to limit based on IP not entirely block IPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `redis` in your project you can very simply implement requests counter for API request. This approach allows you not to just limit robots access, but limit different API request using different policies based on your preferences. Take a loook on [this gem](https://github.com/andreareginato/redis-throttle) or follow [this guide](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/introduction-to-rate-limiting-with-redis/155) if you want to implement limit by yourself.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the gem: `Rack::Attack`!

Battle-tested in production environments.

- GiHub: https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack
- Video from RailsConf: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1UwxsZD6sw

Comment: Hey just wondering, how would this be used in the case where bot IP addresses are dynamic?

Comment: it would still count by IP, and the bot has only a limited number of IPs at it's disposal... so most likely all of them will be flagged and blocked. 
But don't be too aggressive when setting your limits, because of requests from NAT'ed networks..

Comment: My current approach is to block them based on their headers ... Seems to be working well so far!

Comment: you can also use other identifiers than just the IP with Rack::Attack -- the video covers this afaik.

Comment: sure thing. You can also throttle requests based on the path. It can also do blacklists. Very useful gem.

Answer (score 1):

So, for anyone interested, I found an alternative solution that works without adding rack attack or redis. It's a little hacky, but hey, it might help someone else.

```
count = 0
unless Rails.cache.read("user_ip_#{get_ip}_count").nil?
  count = Rails.cache.read("user_ip_#{get_ip}_count") + 1
  if count > 20
    flash[:error] = "You're doing that too much. Slow down."
    redirect_to root_path and return false
  end
end
Rails.cache.write("user_ip_#{get_ip}_count", count, :expires_in => 60.minutes)
```

This limits any requests to the geocoder to 20/hour. For testing purposes:

```
def get_ip
  if Rails.env.production?  
    @ip = request.remote_ip
  else
    @ip = "{YOUR_IP}" 
  end
end
```

**Update**

I thought this was a great idea, but it turns out it doesn't work due to changing IP addresses of crawlers. I have instead implemented this rather simple code:

```
if request.bot?
  Rails.logger.info "Bot Request Denied from #{get_ip}"
  flash[:error] = "Bot detected."
  redirect_to root_path and return false
end
```

Using this handy rails gem: [voight_kampff](https://github.com/biola/Voight-Kampff)

Comment: I think your algorithm is incorrect: if you get a request every 10 minutes, you'll get the the error message after 3h20 (20*10 minutes) since you cache expiration date is reset every time you get a request.